# badge attribute data-badge-caption in materialize css not working?

Tags: css, material-design, materialize

```
<span class="new badge" data-badge-caption="custom caption">4</span>
```

This is still getting me "4 new" instead of "4 custom caption".

I'm using materialize version 0.97.6

Find the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/x8w11aa0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you load the materialize.js file?

It seems to be working for me here: https://jsfiddle.net/xpoh33m6/1/ using the same code as you:

```
<nav>
  <span class="new badge" data-badge-caption="custom caption">4</span>
</nav>
```

Edit: Your code is working with `v0.97.7` but not `v0.97.6` (this feature was possibly only just introduced in `v0.97.7`)

Comment: What is the css url you are adding? I'm using following and not working with that, try below in fiddle

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css

Comment: Can you try with version 0.97.7 ?

Comment: Well this works fine with 0.97.7 and JS is not required.
got the Github issue though [link](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/3015)

I've already used 0.96.6 in my app, so just worried what changes it might bring.

Comment: Do you know which version added this feature?

Comment: looks to be 0.97.7 only.
Update your answer with version details, so that I can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this CSS

```
span.badge[data-badge-caption]::after {
    content: " " attr(data-badge-caption);
}
```